# JPA: Building way to persist data only for a period of time

Tags: jpa, persistence

Is there any existing mechanism in JPA, to persist data only for a period of time?
After this lifespan the data should be dropped.

So that there is no need for polling to cleanup old persisted data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such a mechanism in JPA.

Comment: thank you, i will use @Schedule in a Bean and cleanup old data